# Is possible to add an Azure DevOps Group of users through Azure CLI 'az repos policy required-reviewer create' command?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-policy

At Microsoft documentation we have following section: [Automatically include code reviewers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#automatically-include-code-reviewers)

There are two guides:

1. Default selected that is how to automatically include code reviewers by Browser at your Azure DevOps project repository
2. The other option is to do it through Azure CLI that is the case that I am asking

At the first guide you could find that we are allow to 'Add people and groups to Reviewers.' BUT at the guide to do it through Azure CLI there is nothing about being able to do it with parameter '--required-reviewer-ids'

I wanted to know if it is possible to do it giving ADO Team identifier value to --required-reviewer-ids and this will take in charge to add every team member of this group

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to know if it is possible to do it giving ADO Team identifier
> value to --required-reviewer-ids and this will take in charge to add
> every team member of this group

Yes, you can pass the **Team id** to the `--requried-reviewer-ids` flag to the cmdlet **az repos policy required-reviewer create**. once the team is added as a reviewer it will trigger an email to all the members in the team when there is any pull request.

We have tested this in our local environment it is working fine.

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

[image]